# Downloadable historical traffic data?

Tags: data, transportation, traffic

I'm looking for historical traffic data on a decently large city.
Specifically I need data points that can be used to infer the distribution of vehicle speeds across each road, but I *don't* want the data to be pre-processed (i.e., it should be coming in the form of individual samples, instead of pre-fit distributions to the data).
It doesn't really matter where the data is from, any major city should be fine -- I just need the the traffic pattern to be interesting for analysis.

Is there any source from which I can obtain such data for free and without too much difficulty?
(Ideally it wouldn't be too difficult to map the roads to those from OpenStreetMaps.)

Comment: Define a "decently large city." London, UK or Mexico City.

Comment: @Mapperz: I mean something with an interesting traffic pattern, where routing is actually a problem of interest. San Francisco, Luxembourg, etc. would be great.

Comment: like http://www.dot.ca.gov/dist4/highwayops/hoindex.html

Comment: @Mapperz: I can't find anything on that page that has raw data. It only seems to be the average over many vehicles, which tells me nothing about the shapes of the distributions. Maybe I missed what part of the page you were referring to?

Comment: To obtain raw data, you may have to call the specific DOT you are interested in getting data for.

Comment: If this is open data then I think the place to ask will be the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: @PolyGeo: Haha, yeah. Sadly it's too late for me, but maybe someone else will find it useful :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some historic traffic data from San Francisco:

http://www.mtc.ca.gov/maps_and_data/datamart/traffic/

AND

ftp://ftp.abag.ca.gov/pub/mtc/planning/traffic/

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it. Unfortunately it doesn't look like they have individual vehicle speeds, but are rather just reporting total counts and mean/standard deviations which isn't what I was looking for.